# is it good practice to have a table with only one column holding an ID to separate two similiar entities?

Tags: sql, database, erd

The use case being:
An episode of a serie is an entity and can be watched.
A movie is an entity and can be watched.
watched episodes and movies get stored in an entity called watched.

To see what was watched you could either:

- Have it so your watched entity contains an EpisodeId and a movieId.
- Or you could make a separate entity holding just an Id to give out to watched, and passing his Id as a foreign key to episode and movie.
  This will iron out all the nulls in the database.

Currently we are using the last option however it feels like it is the wrong way to approach this. Since our Program entity doesn't create a new id when a movie/episode is added.

Is there a way to change program so it automaticaly creates an Id for episode/movie or should this be done differently?

[ERD of our current DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD77N.png)

Comment: What are the data types for filmID and afleveringID? Are they auto generated GUIDs?

Comment: auto incremented id's in the database.

Comment: Pity GUIDs would be useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

If to do it by the book, you should have a table "Video", with 3 columns: video_id, video_type, watched_status.
Video type would hold values "movie" or "episode". Watched status: "watched" or "new". So you can filter each time whatever you want.

Otherwise, if you want to have separate table for watched and not watched, you would need remove status column and create Watched_Video, but you should still have Video table, not movie+episode. You would have unique ids in Video table and you can transfer entries from New_Video to Watched_Video without issues with keys.

Comment: The issue with this is that an episode is part of a serie and a movie is not. An episode holds an episode number and a movie does not. There are multiple differences between an episode and a movie.

Comment: ok, so you can have additional columns related to episodes only, preferably in separate table: table Episode_Dictionary containing video_id, episode_number, series_name. In table Video you would still have video_id, video_type, video_name, video_status.